# How to get Ip address in php

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache server 2.2.22, Php 5.4.5 and Mysql 5.5.27 on Windows 7 operating system. Every thing work good. But I don't get Ip address. Here is my Ip address collecting code

```
<?php

//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) 
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    //Is it a proxy address
} 
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) 
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} 
else 
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
//The value of $ip at this point would look something like: "192.0.34.166"
$ip = ip2long($ip);
```

Anyone can help me how can I get Ip address. do I need to change or modify Apache httpd.conf or php.ini file for solving this problem.

Comment: NEVER use it like this. Never trust data sent from client. In http_x_forwarded_for might be anything and it's commonly used to spoof user ip by sending x-forwarded-for with other headers and so can be perfectly masked. Try for example to send this header with custom content to cmyip.com - it will directly display it.

Comment: Better codes than this one should exist on this website already - also with better comments and a discussion which problems these codes come with.

Answer (score 3):

Simple method to get user IP address

```
<?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]


?>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you don't only use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] but also use $client and $forward? I thought $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] always had a value and is never empty.

Comment: @MarcusLind When visitor connecting to your server via proxy server. `REMOTE_ADDR` value replaced with proxy server IP and vistior real IP stored on `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` or `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` . I'm using `@`  on these 2 variables. Because, Some proxy server don't provide visitors real IP address.

Comment: You could update this to more modern versions of PHP by using `??` instead of the `@` operator, e.g., `$client  = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ?? null;`

Answer (score 2):

You can get server IP with [`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`](http://php.net/_SERVER) and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will return the IP address from which the user is viewing.